# Convert a signed number into 16-bit binary value in little endian format

Tags: python-3.x, binary

I need to convert an array containing integers both signed and unsigned into binary vale in little endian format. This is what I tried.I am not able to convert big endian to little endian.

```
data = [-6, -24, -37, -45, -52, -54, -54, -51, -48, -47]
for i in data:
   if (i<0):
       values.append(bin(i & 0xffff).reverse())
   else:
       values.append(bin(i).reverse())
```

Output I got is

```
['0b1111111111111010', '0b1111111111101000', '0b1111111111011011', '0b1111111111010011', '0b1111111111001100', '0b1111111111001010', '0b1111111111001010', '0b1111111111001101', '0b1111111111010000', '0b1111111111010001']
```

**Updated**

To check if the conversion is correct. I tried converting the resulting binary back to integer. Its giving me the wrong results.

```
print("Input {}".format(data))
#integer to little endian binary
values = [x.to_bytes(2, byteorder='big', signed=True) for x in data]
reinterpreted = [int.from_bytes(x, byteorder='little', signed=True) for x in values]
for i in reinterpreted:
    if (i<0):
        final.append(bin(i & 0xffff))
    else:
        final.append(bin(i))
print("Binary {}".format(final))

#little endian binary to integer
for i in final:
    integerValue.append(int(i, base=2))
print("Recalculate input {}".format(integerValue))

Input [-6, -24, -37, -45, -52, -54, -54, -51, -48, -47]
Binary ['0b1111101011111111', '0b1110100011111111', 
'0b1101101111111111', '0b1101001111111111', '0b1100110011111111', 
'0b1100101011111111', '0b1100101011111111', '0b1100110111111111', 
'0b1101000011111111', '0b1101000111111111']
Recalculate input [64255, 59647, 56319, 54271, 52479, 51967, 51967, 
52735, 53503, 53759]
```

Comment: `''.join(bin(x)[2:] for x in foo.to_bytes(2, 'little', signed=True))` should work where `foo` is your integer to convert.

Answer (score 0):

This works perfectly. Converts an integer array into 16bit signed array and vice versa and compares the results.

```
#integer to little endian binary
values = [x.to_bytes(2, byteorder='big', signed=True) for x in ECG_data]
reintermediate = [int.from_bytes(x, byteorder='little', signed=True) for x in values]
for i in reintermediate:
    if (i<0):
        final.append(bin(i & 0xffff)[2:])
    else:
        final.append(bin(i)[2:])

#little endian binary to integer
data = [(int(i, base=2).to_bytes(2, "little")) for i in final]
reinterpreted = [int.from_bytes(x, byteorder='big', signed=True) for x in data]

if ((reinterpreted == ECG_data) == True):
    print("Interpretation is Proper")
else:
    print("Interpretation is wrong")
```